# IR spectra database for inorganic compounds

Tags: reference-request

I would need a database of IR spectra of inorganic compounds, possibly free of charge. For organic compounds there is for example "AIST: Spectral Database for Organic Compounds, SDBS" (https://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/cre_index.cgi), is there something similar for inorganic compounds?

Comment: Have you checked NIST database?

Comment: SciFinder amd Reaxys will have IR spectra but it is not free.